# Дополнительное слово в блок Поделиться

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Добрый день.

Можно ли добавить в скрипт еще одно слово "Поделиться" перед названием соцсети или мессенджера, которое появляется при наведении на него курсора?

Сейчас при наведении иконки ВК, появляется слово "Вконтакте".

При добавлении слова "Поделиться", даже самому тугому пользователю будет понятно, для чего нужна эта кнопка, ну и побудительный глагол в действии.

Например: при наведении на иконку ВК, появляется надпись "Поделиться Вконтакте".

Comment: да можно, не пойму в чём проблема , можно даже регистр символов изменить.

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать поверху уже существующего блока:

Cкриптом пройтись по всем кнопкам и переопределить title.

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName("ya-share2__link");
for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++) {
   link.title = "Поделиться "+ link.title;
}
```

Но я у себя на сайте делаю проще, просто перед всеми кнопками добавляю слово "поделиться". Дело в том, что большинство пользователей не будет наводить на кнопку что бы прочитать title, а на мобильных и планшетах, даже и навести не получится.

Comment: Title в документации — про заголовок контента, которым делятся, а не про текст кнопки. Уберите эту часть ответа, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Роман Парадеев, ага, спасибо.